# is it possible to open bottomSheetDialogFragment via findNavController().navigate(R.id.action, args)

Tags: android, kotlin

Is there any way to call findNavController().navigate(action, args) to open BottomSheetDialogFragment.
Instead of using BottomSheerDialogFragment.show(fragmentManager, tag)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You need to declare your bottom Sheet in your navGraps using `<dialog>` tags and call its action. I am mentioning one example below

In navgraph

```
 <dialog
        android:id="@+id/dialog_bottom_sort"
        android:name="com.android.example.BottomSheetSortDialog"
        tools:layout="@layout/dialog_bottom_sort"/>
```

//this is a sample action open bottom sheet

```
  <action
            android:id="@+id/action_jobList_to_dialog_bottom"
            app:destination="@id/dialog_bottom_sort"
            app:launchSingleTop="true" />
```

//and the fragment from where you want to perform your action

```
navController.navigate(
                JobLatestFragmentDirections.actionJobListToDialogBottom()
            )
```

If you want to pass an argument declares one bundle and attach it to navigate() also you need to mention the same in nav graphs using `<argument>`

```
 val args = Bundle().apply {
                    putString("key", "value")
                }
navController.navigate(R.id.dialog_bottom_sort,args)
```

Note: Your dialog fragment should extend with `BottomSheetDialogFragment()`